# Conditional replacement in R

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I have a dataframe in R that looks like this:

```
Genes       snps    X0  X1  X2  X3  
2   WASH7P  1_14677 0   2   2   2   
3   WASH7P  1_14684 0   1   2   0   
4   WASH7P  1_14685 0   0   0   0
```

Is it possible to do a conditional replacement such that if the the int 2 has a frequency of > 0.5 across columns X0-X3 to replace 2 with 0 and 0 with 2? 
Such that the new dataframe is :

```
    Genes     snps  X0  X1  X2  X3  
2   WASH7P  1_14677 2   0   0   0   
3   WASH7P  1_14684 0   1   2   0   
4   WASH7P  1_14685 0   0   0   0
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another possible method:

```
cbind(df[1:2], t(as.data.frame(apply(df[3:ncol(df)], 1, function(x) {
  if(mean(x == 2) > .5) {
    x[x==0] <- 4
    x - 2} else x}))))
#   Genes    snps X0 X1 X2 X3
#2 WASH7P 1_14677  2  0  0  0
#3 WASH7P 1_14684  0  1  2  0
#4 WASH7P 1_14685  0  0  0  0
```

Inside of the function, `4` was assigned to the `0` values. Then `2` was subtracted from the row, leaving the desired output.

If the name structure of data frame changes, use @akrun's method of column searching. Or if `2` and `0` are simply toy examples and the recoding is much more complex, go with akrun's answer for value specification. This is just another approach without packages.

Comment: This is a good, quick approach. The only problem I had is that the 1s went to -1. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5):

Using `R`, we could create an index for the column names that start with 'X' ('i1').  Then, we get the row index based on the condition that the `rowMeans` of values that are 2 in the 'X' columns is greater than 0.5.  We subset the 'df1' based on the row/column index, loop through the columns (`lapply(...`), then replace the '2' values with '0' and '0' with '2' using `recode` from `library(car)`. Assign the output back to the subset of rows/columns of 'df1'.

```
library(car)
i1 <- grep('^X', names(df1))
i2 <- rowMeans(df1[i1]==2)> 0.5
df1[i1][i2,] <- lapply(df1[i1][i2,], recode, '2=0;0=2')
df1
#   Genes    snps X0 X1 X2 X3
#2 WASH7P 1_14677  2  0  0  0
#3 WASH7P 1_14684  0  1  2  0
#4 WASH7P 1_14685  0  0  0  0
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Genes = c("WASH7P", "WASH7P", "WASH7P"),
snps = c("1_14677", 
"1_14684", "1_14685"), X0 = c(0L, 0L, 0L), X1 = c(2L, 1L, 0L), 
X2 = c(2L, 2L, 0L), X3 = c(2L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("Genes", 
"snps", "X0", "X1", "X2", "X3"), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c("2", "3", "4"))
```